# python doc to docx conversion, comtypes.Documents.Open throwing ValueError: NULL COM pointer access

Tags: python, django, windows, apache

### **Background**

I have an application, wherein I am suppose to convert .doc to .docx. After which .docx files are processed for data mining. This service is accessed by the end-user using a web interface. The web application is developed in Django 1.6.

To convert .doc to .docx, we require Windows platform with MS Office installed. Having said that, I have a AWS Windows Server 2012 R2 instance(it's Windows 64bit) running. I am using Apache(64bit) with mod_wsgi and Python 2.7.8(64bit).

---

Now, here is my code to convert .doc to .docx

```
import tempfile, sys
import comtypes, comtypes.client

def convert(source):
    tmpfile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
    tmpname = tmpfile.name + ".docx"
    tmpfile.close()
    os.unlink(tmpfile.name)

    try:
        comtypes.CoInitialize();
        wordapp = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')
        doc = wordapp.Documents.Open(source, ReadOnly=True)
        doc.SaveAs(tmpname, FileFormat=16)
        doc.Close()
        wordapp.Quit()
    except:
        print sys.exc_info()

    if os.path.exists(tmpname):
        return tmpname
    else:
        return None
```

The error that I am getting is

```
(<type 'exceptions.ValueError'>, ValueError('NULL COM pointer access',), <traceback object at 0x00000085CE65AC08>)
```

on line

```
doc = wordapp.Documents.Open(source, ReadOnly=True)
```

But the interesting thing that's happening is, this error only occurs when I use the web interface. That is if I go through Apache and call this code.

I have tried to run this code directly from command line as a script, it works just fine.

When conversion happens as a part of Django view, I am getting this error.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Prathamesh

Comment: Has the apache user (or the user that runs apache) rights to read the file?

Comment: I am running on windows server and apache is running with Admin access. So, I guess Apache has all the rights to read the file.

Comment: @PrathameshPaiyyar happy to be corrected, and I know this doesn't answer your question, but running your web server as admin sounds like a bad idea to me.

Comment: @RobertGrant, We are testing the code on Windows Server R2 2012 for right now. I will definitely consider you advice. Thanks.

Comment: We have the exactly same setup, and we're experiencing the same error. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 6):

If you are still having this issue, this is what helped me for exactly the same layout of AWS(Win2012)-Apache(64bit)-Django:

Change the DCOM Config Settings:

1. Start -> dcomcnfg.exe
2. Computers -> My Computer
3. DCOM Config
4. Select the *Microsoft Word 97-2003 Documents* -> Properties
5. Tab Identity, change from **Launching User** to **Interactive User**

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Flask/Dash (running on Win2012) and the solution was to use server (web) path to the source - i.e. http://myserverapp/source/file.doc for reading the file instead of C:\users...\file.doc.